# Exception caught by widgets library Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading the data from firebase firestore I have different collections when I am reading from this one this error comes out.
Here is my code

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

var DTSpH, datePH, pPHH;

class PH extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'pH';
  @override
  _LightState createState() => _LightState();
}

class _LightState extends State<PH> {
  _LightState();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    while (true) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: null,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          ],
          title: Text('Previous Light Data'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: null,
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore.collection('Previous pH Data').snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                datePH = (document["DataAndTime"]);
                pPHH = (document["pH"]);
                print(pPHH);
                DTSpH= pPHH.toString();
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
                    child: Text("pH: " + DTSpH + "   " + "On " +datePH ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================

```
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#5bb4e):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> StreamBuilder:file:///Users/mahmoudabdelaziz/StudioProjects/newgreen/lib/screens/pH.dart:40:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:7)
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:105:23)
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:121:12)
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
#5      _LightState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:QUGreen/screens/pH.dart:52:33)
#6      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#7      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#8      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
#9      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#10     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#11     ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44)
#12     _LightState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:QUGreen/screens/pH.dart:62:18)
#13     StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:442:81)
#14     _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#15     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4918:27)
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:15)
#17     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4976:11)
#18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4528:5)
#19     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2672:19)
#20     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#21     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:367:5)
#22     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#23     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#24     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#28     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#29     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#30     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

====================================================================================================

But the reading process is done successfully because I printed it I do not know what to do any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your code from this:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore.collection('Previous pH Data').snapshots(),
```

to this:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('Previous pH Data').snapshots(),
```

Comment: did it but same error